# An output directory which doesn't correspond to existing modules is found

Tags: intellij-idea

An output directory which doesn't correspond to existing modules is found  under C:\Users. Clean Up... Do not ask again. If i choose clean up, this will affect my project?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking. Can you provide more detail?

Comment: What is the exact path of the directory? Which files does it contain?